# USB-C splitter to USB-C video and USB data

Tags: usb, video

I want a hub/splitter/device that takes

**input:** one usb-c in (with displayport alternate mode)

1. **output 1:** one usb-c video out (displayport alternate mode)
2. **output 2:** one or more data outputs (can be usb type c or usb type a)

I don't need power delivery. After searching for a long time, I haven't found any device that supports that, despite there being 10.000 different usb hubs.

Comment: Why do you need USB-C display-out instead of DisplayPort?

Comment: @JMY1000 because my display only has USB type C connector and no physical DisplayPort connector: Asus ZenScreen MB16AC

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that with Thunderbolt 4 I will finally get the hardware I want. Since all Thunderbolt 3 devices could also pass USB C DisplayPort alternate mode. And assuming Thunderbolt 4 keeps this feature and now adds hubs, I have a solution where I can split off a USB-C DisplayPort signal.

This is highly speculative but it makes sense. Price could be around $149.00 according to OWC.

https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-thunderbolt-hub

https://thunderbolttechnology.net/sites/default/files/intel-thunderbolt4-announcement-press-deck.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is now a docking station with USB-C data, USB-C displayport out and USB-A hub. Available with Thunderbolt 3 or regular USB-C host connection.

https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-docking-station-wd19-180w/apd/210-ariq/pc-accessories

It's just a bit pricey at USD ~250